# What's really happening when this Filter(All(Column),...) syntax is evaluated?

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have only one table named 'Data' in my PowerBI Desktop model, which contains [Datetime], [Type], [Name], and several other columns.

I choose a specific Type="B" by clicking on a graph, and a period of time with a slicer on Datetime, and then use the measures below to calculate how many different names there are in Type "A"(as expected, there should be no record with A and B at the same time).
That's when I'm totally confused by the result:

(My PowerBI version is the latest release in April,2019.)

---

```
Wrong =
CALCULATE (
    DISTINCTCOUNT ( Data[Name] ),
    FILTER ( ALL ( Data[Type] ), Data[Type] = "A" )
)
```

While this measure turns out to be the right one:

```
Correct = 
CALCULATE ( 
    DISTINCTCOUNT ( Data[Name] ), 
    FILTER ( Data, Data[Type] = "A" ) 
)
```

---

What I think is happening (probably missing something important):

Since the two measures share the same explicit filter context outside `CALCULATE`, and what they finally calculate are the same, the only problem would be "what's the final context provided by `FILTER`"?

With the Correct version, `FILTER` simply takes the (Type="B" + Datetime) subset, try to find rows with Type "A" inside the subset(Type="B" + Type="A" + Datetime), and it just fails. So `FILTER` gives nothing to final calculation, which turns out to be blank as expected(there should be no A Type record when I choose Type B).

With the Wrong version, `FILTER` (with only one column) ignores all filter context on Type(originally "B"), then it applies a new one (Type="A") to replace the original one. And since each column is filtered separatedly, the filter on Datetime does not change at all. So the final context taken by `CALCULATE` should be a subset which contains Type "A" and the selected period of time at the same time(Type="A" + Datetime), which makes the final result "the number of distinct name of Type A during the time", having nothing to do with what Type I chose at first.

---

But the thing is, according to the strange result it gives, `[Wrong]` does absolutely not what I'm thinking of, and I have no clue on it. I've tried many ways I think reasonable to test how it works, but they just fail...

Thank you for any advice!

---

I made a tiny pbix file for test(with the same structure and problem):
https://pan.baidu.com/s/1gNZDNlICFLkMdPpPArb8cQ
If needed, use yf7f to download it.

Comment: This version will be a bit more performant                Correct :=
CALCULATE ( DISTINCTCOUNT ( Data[Name] ), Data[Type] = "A" )

Comment: You are absolutely right! I used this one at first, then I transform it to the Wrong version just to make it easier to see the difference between Correct and Wrong .And I still come up with no conclusion.According to "Difinitive Guide", the two syntaxs are the same,  equivalent to each other.

Comment: I've found the ultimate answer (the answer below). Still thank you for helping me so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `FILTER` function takes a table as its first argument. This table is evaluated within the filter context you are operating in.

In the `Correct` version, that means when you pass in `Data`, that table is filtered on `Type = "B"` and `Datetime` according to your slicer selections. You then add the condition `Data[Type] = "A"` which is not true for anything in the filtered `Data` set since you already picked `"B"` for the type. Therefore, it returns blank since the table is empty.

---

**Edit:** Scratch what I said before and look at an example. Start with this as a full table:

```
Name  Type  Datetime
Alex  A     1/3/2019
Alex  A     1/4/2019
Bob   A     1/5/2019
Bob   B     1/5/2019
Bob   A     1/7/2019
Carla B     1/3/2019
Carla B     1/4/2019
Dan   A     1/6/2019
```

If I slice on type `B` and dates `1/3/2019 - 1/5/2019`, here are the remaining rows:

```
Name  Type  Datetime
Bob   B     1/5/2019
Carla B     1/3/2019
Carla B     1/4/2019
```

When we calculate `ALL( Data[Type] )` within this context we get the following table, which is the same as if you remove the `Type` slicer but keep the date slicer:

```
Name  Type  Datetime
Alex  A     1/3/2019
Alex  A     1/4/2019
Bob   A     1/5/2019
Bob   B     1/5/2019
Carla B     1/3/2019
Carla B     1/4/2019
```

Now when you add the `Data[Type] = "A"` condition you get this table, which is the same as if you had originally filtered on `A` instead of `B` (and keep the date slicer), you get the following:

```
Name  Type  Datetime
Alex  A     1/3/2019
Alex  A     1/4/2019
Bob   A     1/5/2019
```

This clearly has two distinct names instead of none. In the `Correct` version, the difference is that you filter for type `A` on the 2nd table above instead of the 3rd.

Basically, the `ALL` undoes the selection of type that you chose with the slicer.

---

Note: What I said before about indirectly affecting things isn't what's happening here. That's a concern when you are doing a context transition from row context to filter context, but doesn't apply here. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Thank you SO SO MUCH with "indirectly affected"!I feel a BIG step ahead than 1 hour ago.Here's a further question:if FILTER ( ALL ( Data[Type] ), Data[Type] = "A" ) just reset filter on Type and keep all other columns in their original context, since all other columns have been iterated under Type="B", there should still be no row visible after the reset on Type from "B" to "A", because all the original rows visible are the same rows with Type "B"...So the result of Wrong should be blank as well, 
 right?What did I miss?

Comment: Step 1: I filter all columns with Type "B" outside CALCULATE as original context;Step 2: I filter Type with "A", leaving all other columns filtered with Type "B" inside CALCULATE.The final context combined should be nothing, while the truth is not----it returns a strange value instead of blank, why is this happening?

Comment: Thanks a lot for such a detailed explanation!Now along with the conclusion "the ALL undoes the selection of type that you chose with the slicer", it seems I'm right back where I started----"having nothing to do with what Type I chose at first".But it is just not what's really happening.In fact, measure Wrong result in different values if I slice different Type at first step:When I choose Type "A", Wrong gives the same value as Correct;When it's not "A" on slicer, like "B" or "C"，then the Wrong results are totally unpridictable...

Comment: I've found a new clue: if I delete the slicer on Datetime, then measure Wrong would behave just as we have expected(always the number of Type "A" regardless of what Type I choose).With the slicer turned on(which means at least one date is not included), Wrong goes wrong immediatly. The same thing happens not only on Datetime, but also on all other slicers.That is,if I need Wrong to behave as expected, the only slicer I can have is on Type. Any idea to this?

Comment: Do you have a pbix file you can share that demonstrates your issue? It's difficult to tell exactly what's happening when I can't see all the tables, relations, filters, and measures involved.

Comment: I do made one small pbix file for test with the same structure and problem,but I don't know how to upload here...

Comment: A link to any service like Dropbox or Google Drive is fine.

Comment: Sorry I cannot reach either of them, try the link I paste to the end of question.I've decided to pour my time back to the book "Definitive Guide", hoping I can understand the behavior thoroughly.I 'll share my conclusion once I get it!

Comment: I've found the ultimate answer, which I show below. Still thank you for helping me so much!

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I've found the reason why it is happening!
It is called the overwrite of arbitrarily shaped filters.
The complete explanation can be found on "Definitive Guide to DAX", chapter 10, page 439-443.

Just be careful to use more than one filter on two or more columns of the same table, which  is the easiest way that may cause the problem!